# Is this an ambiguous reference?

Tags: ambiguity

If you go to A, the B will C; I've also attached it to this e-mail.

Is "it" referring to A or B?

Comment: The question itself is ambiguous.  I think the specifics of A, B, and C are necessary.  Specifically: which ones can be attached to an e-mail?  "If you go to *school* the *teacher* will *give you my report card*."  -- "It" = report card.  "If you go to *Kentucky*, the *map* will *be available at any gas station*." -- "It" = map.  If you go to *page 5,* the *author's intent* will *become obvious.*  "It" = page 5.  "If you go to *my pdf,* the *professor's assignment* will *be more clear.*  -- "It" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the sentence is entirely ambiguous. I suggest referring to A, B, or C directly instead of using the pronoun. Also the semicolon is a bit strange.

If you go to A, the B will C. I've attached A to this email.

Comment: Why? The sentences are related.